# my function is not a function in my console

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have this code

```
$('.ajax').live('click', function() {

    $(function() {
        $('.ajax').live('click', function() {
        $.get($(this).attr('href'),{},function(data) {
        alert("ok");
        });
        return false;
      });
});
```

and in my console I'm getting

```
TypeError: $(...).live is not a function
```

What's wrong with my js code ?
i'm using jquery-1.9.1.js

Comment: is 'ajax' a class? or you trying to make an ajax call?

Comment: Why do you have a document ready inside your click function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`live` has been replaced by `on`.

You should rename `live` to `on` and it will work.

Upgrade guide from jquery can be found [here](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/).

Also, the code seems a little duplicate to me. This should also work:

```
$('.ajax').live('click', function()
{
  $.get($(this).attr('href'),{}, function(data)
  {
    alert("ok");
  });

  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

From the jQuery docs: "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated"

https://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: version deprecated: 1.7, removed: 1.9

Answer (score 0):

`live` is deprecated and replaced with `on` after jQuery 1.7

replace `$('.ajax').live('click', function()` with `$('.ajax').on('click', function()`

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this is the reason, seems like removed.

http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#live-removed

According to the link:

> The .live() method has been deprecated since jQuery 1.7 and has been
>   removed in 1.9. We recommend upgrading code to use the .on() method
>   instead.